# Output incoming UDP data to new terminals with Python3.7 on Windows

Tags: python, shell, command-line, terminal, udp

I have a client/server UDP program running on python3.7 on Windows. After establishing a connection, the client listens for incoming data from the server. Each time a client receives data/message (from server), a new terminal should open displaying that message and the client should be able to respond to that message on that terminal. So if a client receives 4 incoming messages from the server, 4 terminals should open with each one displaying their corresponding message.

As of now, my program works just fine but on one terminal.
Could someone please help me? I was able to make a new terminal open for each incoming message with  os.system("start cmd") but that's as far as I was able to get. These terminal instances just point to the project's directory with nothing running on them and I understand why, this is just as much 'progress' as I was able to make.
Here is the sample of my code I am referring to :

```html
def clientListen():
    while 1:
        try:
            data, server = client_listen_socket.recvfrom(1024)
            if data:
                reply = pickle.loads(data)
                if str(reply) == 'Connection Successful':
                    print('\n  ~~~   INCOMING MESSAGE FROM ' + str(serverName) + '   ~~~\n') #REPLACE->localhost
                    print(reply)
                    clientServerConnectionOutput()
                else:
                    # *OPEN TERMINAL DISPLAYING REPLY* 
                    print('\n  ~~~   INCOMING MESSAGE FROM ' + str(serverName) + '   ~~~\n') #REPLACE->localhost
                    print(reply)
        except socket.error:
            pass
```

So each time it receives data, (if data), under the else clause, this is where I want a new terminal to open displaying the reply.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: have you tried allowing your program to accept command line arguments and then just reopening it every time you get a connection and pass the connection as an argument to the new instance of your program?

Comment: I am not sure if I'm following. Right now i have a send and listen function in my client, and each time it receives data from the server, I want a terminal to open displaying that data. I don't have any code or key words referring to anything terminal related. I know I need to add some terminal-related lines to my program but I don't understand the os or subprocess documentation and have been having a lot of difficulty.

Comment: sharing your code might help us under stand what you want

Comment: Okay, I just added it to my post